# Failed Dell PERC H700 Firmware Upgrade with Windows 2008 R2 BitLocker Enabled

Tags: dell, firmware, bitlocker

I attempted to use the Dell openManage Server Update Utility within Windows to update the firmware on the Dell PERC H700 controller and was given the following error:

'The update package cannot be run because the operating system is running Windows BitLocker Drive Encryption with TPM measurements. Please disable BitLocker and then run the update package.'

I'm not a big fan of diabling Bitlocker just to do the Firmware upddate. Has anybody had a similar problem and what was your workaround if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to figure this one out and it applies to any sort of Dell Firmware Update you might need to apply.

1. In Windows Server 2008 R2, you don't 'Disable' BitLocker, you 'Suspend' it... Go ahead and do this on your System Drive (C:).
2. Even after suspending Bitlocker, the Dell OpenManage Server Update Utility (SUU) will throw the same error about BitLocker being enabled.
3. Use the [Dell Repository Manager](http://content.dell.com/us/en/enterprise/d/solutions/repository-manager.aspx) to build a Linux ISO that includes all the system updates for your particular server model. Burn the ISO to a DVD. Its important to create this disk for Linux, since the Dell Systems Build and Update utility is running under Linux .
4. Reboot the machine with the Dell Systems Management DVD that was included with the Server... Choose Firmware update and choose Update from CD... Insert the DVD that you burned, this should detect the firmware updates that the machine needs and you can proceed with the installation. The system will reboot to Windows when the updates are complete.
5. Once logged into Windows again, Resume BitLocker.